# concatenating IQueryable data sets with MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# and Entity Framework 5. I am generating a JSON structure which is the result of a LINQ query. In the controller I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ICD10ConditionSearch(string ICD10SearchTerm)
{
    CommonCodeEntities dataContextCommonCodes = new CommonCodeEntities(ConnectionString);

    IQueryable<ICD10Codes> codes = dataContextCommonCodes.ICD10Codes.
        Where(m => m.ICD10CodeTitle.Contains(ICD10SearchTerm));
    return Json(codes);
}
```

This works correctly and returns the expected results.

What I *really* want to do is to use a lst of search terms and concatonate the result. When I use the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ICD10ConditionSearch(string ICD10SearchTerms)
{
    String[] terms = ICD10SearchTerms.Split(' ');
    IQueryable<ICD10Codes> codes = Enumerable.Empty<ICD10Codes>().AsQueryable();
    IQueryable<ICD10Codes> codeLocal;            

    CommonCodeEntities dataContextCommonCodes = new CommonCodeEntities(ConnectionString);

    foreach (var term in terms)
    {
        codeLocal = dataContextCommonCodes.ICD10Codes.Where(m => m.ICD10CodeTitle.Contains(term));
        codes = codes.Concat(codeLocal);
    }
    return Json(codes);
}
```

This generate the following error `This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code`. I have tried other variants of Concat() with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating your dataset eg. `dataContextCommonCodes.ICD10Codes.Where(m => m.ICD10CodeTitle.Contains(term)).ToArray()` before the concat

Comment: try using the Add function instead of concat?

Comment: @elvis IQueryable are read only. As said by Luke, the element you want to concat need to be IEnumerable : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove foreach and try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ICD10ConditionSearch(string ICD10SearchTerms)
{
    String[] terms = ICD10SearchTerms.Split(' ');
    CommonCodeEntities dataContextCommonCodes = new CommonCodeEntities(ConnectionString);
    IQueryable<ICD10Codes> codes = dataContextCommonCodes.ICD10Codes
       .Where(e => terms.Any(k => e.ICD10CodeTitle.Contains(k)).AsQueryable();

    return Json(codes);
}
```

Why you just don't use `List<ICD10Codes>` instate of `IQueryable<ICD10Codes>`?

Comment: Thank you, a perfect and elegant reponse. Also, changing IQueryable to IEnumerable helped as well.